# Becoming a master from a newbie at Computer Science and Electronics

Tags: resource-request, textbook, careers

I want to learn about Computers and Electronics and presently don't hold any kind of degree in the same. My urge to learn is entirely driven by my interest and curiosity for these subjects. I will be teaching my self at my own pace using materials available online.

But being a newbie to all this, and as these fields are very broad, I find it difficult to find where to start. I would like to do everything systematically and not just randomly picking up stuff, because all it does is to create loopholes and confusions. I would like to gain some insight regarding the same from your past experiences at learning.

So my only question is, from where should I start my learning process i.e. a kind of topic list which I must follow? For instance, what do university programs teach, in what order, and why do they prioritize the way they do?

Comment: Adding more specifics about what you want to learn/be able to do would be very helpful. If you're question is simply "How can I learn everything", that seems far too broad to be answered in a single answer.

Comment: Yes, your question is too broad. "Computer Science and Electronics" is an incredibly broad range. You need to narrow it down. The best way to do that is to find a person, perhaps at a local school or university who is already an expert and explore with her/him your goals. Imagine that you are entering a vast jungle about which you know nothing. You would be wise to find a guide first. The reason that a university education is valuable (from a learning standpoint) is that others who do understand the goals and how to achieve them can help you with your own goals.

Comment: I fear that this question here will result in so many "options" that you can't possibly follow them and you will have nothing better than random advice. And expect mastery of even a small part of the landscape to take a long time to achieve. Ten years? More? The best time to plant a tree is 40 years ago. The second best time is now, but it won't seem like a tree for quite a while.

Comment: What level, experience do you have (you say no degree, but do you have other experience, qualifications)? What are you main goals? I will vote to put on hold, but will be happy to re-open, if you add the specific things asked for.

Comment: I think you should grab a raspberry pi and build you're own Robot or home automation system, you would be able to learn a lot in the process : Shell, C, automation, basic electronics, python, node.js. When you'll have the project done you'll have get through a lot of the main basics of programming, embedded systems, web, and electronics subjects. But to truly progress you should not only follow tutorials but also try to understand stuff and mess around.

Comment: I narrowed the question in the (edited) last paragraph by citing an example, and wonder if the question can be reopened in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

I am glad to see your question, because 40 years ago, I was a child who was extremely interested in electronics, radio and computers, and the resources seemed much more limited then.

I would say, because the field is so broad, it does not matter where you start. Pick something that interests you and go as far as you can with it. My first interest was in building an amplifier to use with a microphone so I could make loud noises (your personal goal does not have to make sense to anyone else) so I read books about transistor amplifiers in hopes of finding a simple design.

My suggeztions are:

- Find an Amateur Radio group and participate
- build some simple kits
- write some simple programs
- use the relevant Stack Exchange sites
- choose some specific goals or projects
- "*Nevah, nevah, nevah give up*!" (Winston Churchill)

Don't worry if you don't get to your specific goals - I never built that amplifier - you will learn so much on the way, and become a specialist in something. I eventually became an expert in small transmitting loop antennas, C and data communications. *Qapla'!*

Comment: Hardware is somewhat less important than it was 40 years ago. Amateur Radio is similarly less relevant nowadays.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but if the OP wants to learn about "computers and electronics" then hardware is pretty important. And since Amateurs do much of the experimental programming and hardware design, I think they are just as relevant as they were in Edwin Howard Armstrong's day. 750,000 hams in the US, twice as many in Japan and millions more throughout the world would probably disagree with you.

Answer (score 2):

We can't help you find a topic.  You must focus yourself on a single point of entry.  There are already high-quality, pre-arranged curriculums available in every topic at a high level, and they are called *textbooks*.  See if you can find one that is an introduction to the field that you're looking at.  You might be surprised at how close of a match you can make.

I strongly suggest that your first step is choosing a textbook.  A textbook is an essential guide for a self-learner, even if you can't learn from a textbook.  Why?  Because a textbook doesn't just explain the material.  A good textbook **organizes** and lays out the material.  A textbook guarantees that you go through in a reasonable order, that you build on the knowledge that you've gained, and that your exposure is pretty thorough.

If you don't learn well from textbooks, then use it only as a sketch of what you should be covering.  You can glance through the first chapter, scan over the topics, and go to Google or YouTube to learn the material itself.  You'll know you've successfully learned the material in a chapter when you can scan over the text and it makes sense.